# Zalenium Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 502

Tags: kubernetes, kubernetes-helm, zalenium

I am trying to deploy the zalenium helm chart in my newly deployed aks Kuberbetes (1.9.6) cluster in Azure. But I don't get it to work. The pod is giving the log below:

> [bram@xforce zalenium]$ kubectl logs -f zalenium-zalenium-hub-6bbd86ff78-m25t2 Kubernetes service account found. Copying files for Dashboard... cp: cannot create regular file '/home/seluser/videos/index.html': Permission denied cp: cannot create directory '/home/seluser/videos/css': Permission denied cp: cannot create directory '/home/seluser/videos/js': Permission denied Starting Nginx reverse proxy... Starting Selenium Hub... ..........08:49:14.052 [main] INFO o.o.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3 - Selenium build info: version: '3.12.0', revision: 'unknown' 08:49:14.120 [main] INFO o.o.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3 - Launching Selenium Grid hub on port 4445 ...08:49:15.125 [main] INFO d.z.e.z.c.k.KubernetesContainerClient - Initialising Kubernetes support ..08:49:15.650 [main] WARN d.z.e.z.c.k.KubernetesContainerClient - Error initialising Kubernetes support. io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [get] for kind: [Pod] with name: [zalenium-zalenium-hub-6bbd86ff78-m25t2] in namespace: [default] failed. at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:62) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException.launderThrowable(KubernetesClientException.java:71) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:206) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.get(BaseOperation.java:162) at de.zalando.ep.zalenium.container.kubernetes.KubernetesContainerClient.(KubernetesContainerClient.java:87) at de.zalando.ep.zalenium.container.ContainerFactory.createKubernetesContainerClient(ContainerFactory.java:35) at de.zalando.ep.zalenium.container.ContainerFactory.getContainerClient(ContainerFactory.java:22) at de.zalando.ep.zalenium.proxy.DockeredSeleniumStarter.(DockeredSeleniumStarter.java:59) at de.zalando.ep.zalenium.registry.ZaleniumRegistry.(ZaleniumRegistry.java:74) at de.zalando.ep.zalenium.registry.ZaleniumRegistry.(ZaleniumRegistry.java:62) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) at org.openqa.grid.web.Hub.(Hub.java:93) at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3$2.launch(GridLauncherV3.java:291) at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.launch(GridLauncherV3.java:122) at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.main(GridLauncherV3.java:82) Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLPeerUnverifiedException: Hostname kubernetes.default.svc not verified: certificate: sha256/OyzkRILuc6LAX4YnMAIGrRKLmVnDgLRvCasxGXDhSoc= DN: CN=client, O=system:masters subjectAltNames: [10.0.0.1] at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connectTls(RealConnection.java:308) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.establishProtocol(RealConnection.java:268) at okhttp3.internal.connection.RealConnection.connect(RealConnection.java:160) at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findConnection(StreamAllocation.java:256) at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.findHealthyConnection(StreamAllocation.java:134) at okhttp3.internal.connection.StreamAllocation.newStream(StreamAllocation.java:113) at okhttp3.internal.connection.ConnectInterceptor.intercept(ConnectInterceptor.java:42) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) at okhttp3.internal.cache.CacheInterceptor.intercept(CacheInterceptor.java:93) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) at okhttp3.internal.http.BridgeInterceptor.intercept(BridgeInterceptor.java:93) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) at okhttp3.internal.http.RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.intercept(RetryAndFollowUpInterceptor.java:125) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.ImpersonatorInterceptor.intercept(ImpersonatorInterceptor.java:56) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.utils.HttpClientUtils$2.intercept(HttpClientUtils.java:107) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:147) at okhttp3.internal.http.RealInterceptorChain.proceed(RealInterceptorChain.java:121) at okhttp3.RealCall.getResponseWithInterceptorChain(RealCall.java:200) at okhttp3.RealCall.execute(RealCall.java:77) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:379) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleResponse(OperationSupport.java:344) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:313) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.OperationSupport.handleGet(OperationSupport.java:296) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.handleGet(BaseOperation.java:770) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.getMandatory(BaseOperation.java:195) ... 16 common frames omitted 08:49:15.651 [main] INFO d.z.e.z.c.k.KubernetesContainerClient - About to clean up any left over selenium pods created by Zalenium Usage:  [options] Options: --debug, -debug  : enables LogLevel.FINE. Default: false --version, -version Displays the version and exits. Default: false -browserTimeout  in seconds : number of seconds a browser session is allowed to hang while a WebDriver command is running (example: driver.get(url)). If the timeout is reached while a WebDriver command is still processing, the session will quit. Minimum value is 60. An unspecified, zero, or negative value means wait indefinitely. -matcher, -capabilityMatcher  class name : a class implementing the CapabilityMatcher interface. Specifies the logic the hub will follow to define whether a request can be assigned to a node. For example, if you want to have the matching process use regular expressions instead of exact match when specifying browser version. ALL nodes of a grid ecosystem would then use the same capabilityMatcher, as defined here. -cleanUpCycle  in ms : specifies how often the hub will poll running proxies for timed-out (i.e. hung) threads. Must also specify "timeout" option -custom  : comma separated key=value pairs for custom grid extensions. NOT RECOMMENDED -- may be deprecated in a future revision. Example: -custom myParamA=Value1,myParamB=Value2 -host  IP or hostname : usually determined automatically. Most commonly useful in exotic network configurations (e.g. network with VPN) Default: 0.0.0.0 -hubConfig  filename: a JSON file (following grid2 format), which defines the hub properties -jettyThreads, -jettyMaxThreads  : max number of threads for Jetty. An unspecified, zero, or negative value means the Jetty default value (200) will be used. -log  filename : the filename to use for logging. If omitted, will log to STDOUT -maxSession  max number of tests that can run at the same time on the node, irrespective of the browser used -newSessionWaitTimeout  in ms : The time after which a new test waiting for a node to become available will time out. When that happens, the test will throw an exception before attempting to start a browser. An unspecified, zero, or negative value means wait indefinitely. Default: 600000 -port  : the port number the server will use. Default: 4445 -prioritizer  class name : a class implementing the Prioritizer interface. Specify a custom Prioritizer if you want to sort the order in which new session requests are processed when there is a queue. Default to null ( no priority = FIFO ) -registry  class name : a class implementing the GridRegistry interface. Specifies the registry the hub will use. Default: de.zalando.ep.zalenium.registry.ZaleniumRegistry -role  options are [hub], [node], or [standalone]. Default: hub -servlet, -servlets  : list of extra servlets the grid (hub or node) will make available. Specify multiple on the command line: -servlet tld.company.ServletA -servlet tld.company.ServletB. The servlet must exist in the path: /grid/admin/ServletA /grid/admin/ServletB -timeout, -sessionTimeout  in seconds : Specifies the timeout before the server automatically kills a session that hasn't had any activity in the last X seconds. The test slot will then be released for another test to use. This is typically used to take care of client crashes. For grid hub/node roles, cleanUpCycle must also be set. -throwOnCapabilityNotPresent  true or false : If true, the hub will reject all test requests if no compatible proxy is currently registered. If set to false, the request will queue until a node supporting the capability is registered with the grid. -withoutServlet, -withoutServlets  : list of default (hub or node) servlets to disable. Advanced use cases only. Not all default servlets can be disabled. Specify multiple on the command line: -withoutServlet tld.company.ServletA -withoutServlet tld.company.ServletB org.openqa.grid.common.exception.GridConfigurationException: Error creating class with de.zalando.ep.zalenium.registry.ZaleniumRegistry : null at org.openqa.grid.web.Hub.(Hub.java:97) at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3$2.launch(GridLauncherV3.java:291) at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.launch(GridLauncherV3.java:122) at org.openqa.grid.selenium.GridLauncherV3.main(GridLauncherV3.java:82) Caused by: java.lang.ExceptionInInitializerError at de.zalando.ep.zalenium.registry.ZaleniumRegistry.(ZaleniumRegistry.java:74) at de.zalando.ep.zalenium.registry.ZaleniumRegistry.(ZaleniumRegistry.java:62) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance0(Native Method) at sun.reflect.NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(NativeConstructorAccessorImpl.java:62) at sun.reflect.DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.newInstance(DelegatingConstructorAccessorImpl.java:45) at java.lang.reflect.Constructor.newInstance(Constructor.java:423) at java.lang.Class.newInstance(Class.java:442) at org.openqa.grid.web.Hub.(Hub.java:93) ... 3 more Caused by: java.lang.NullPointerException at java.util.TreeMap.putAll(TreeMap.java:313) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.withLabels(BaseOperation.java:411) at io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.dsl.base.BaseOperation.withLabels(BaseOperation.java:48) at de.zalando.ep.zalenium.container.kubernetes.KubernetesContainerClient.deleteSeleniumPods(KubernetesContainerClient.java:393) at de.zalando.ep.zalenium.container.kubernetes.KubernetesContainerClient.initialiseContainerEnvironment(KubernetesContainerClient.java:339) at de.zalando.ep.zalenium.container.ContainerFactory.createKubernetesContainerClient(ContainerFactory.java:38) at de.zalando.ep.zalenium.container.ContainerFactory.getContainerClient(ContainerFactory.java:22) at de.zalando.ep.zalenium.proxy.DockeredSeleniumStarter.(DockeredSeleniumStarter.java:59) ... 11 more ...........................................................................................................................................................................................GridLauncher failed to start after 1 minute, failing... % Total % Received % Xferd Average Speed Time Time Time Current Dload Upload Total Spent Left Speed 100 182 100 182 0 0 36103 0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 45500

A describe pod gives:
Warning Unhealthy 4m (x12 over 6m) kubelet, aks-agentpool-93668098-0 Readiness probe failed: HTTP probe failed with statuscode: 502

Zalenium Image Version(s):
dosel/zalenium:3

If using Kubernetes, specify your environment, and if relevant your manifests:
I use the templates as is from https://github.com/zalando/zalenium/tree/master/docs/k8s/helm

I guess it has to do something with rbac because of this part
"Error initialising Kubernetes support. io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [get] for kind: [Pod] with name: [zalenium-zalenium-hub-6bbd86ff78-m25t2] in namespace: [default] failed. at "

I created a clusterrole and clusterrolebinding for the service account zalenium-zalenium that is automatically created by the Helm chart.

```
kubectl create clusterrole zalenium --verb=get,list,watch,update,delete,create,patch --resource=pods,deployments,secrets

kubectl create clusterrolebinding zalenium --clusterrole=zalnium --serviceaccount=zalenium-zalenium --namespace=default
```

Comment: I can see a typo in your last command: --clusterrole=zalnium

Comment: i made a typo indeed, but fixing the typo didn't help unfornately

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Issue had to do with Azure's AKS and Kubernetes. It has been fixed.
See github issue [399](https://github.com/Azure/AKS/issues/399)

Answer (score 0):

If the typo, mentioned by Ignacio, is not the case why don't you just do

```
kubectl create clusterrolebinding zalenium --clusterrole=cluster-admin serviceaccount=zalenium-zalenium
```

Note: no need to specify a namespace if creating cluster role binding, as it is cluster wide (role binding goes with namespaces).

Comment: Fixing the typo didn't help. And with your option of binding the zalenium SA to the cluster-admin rol didn't help either unfortunately. Still get the error:
`Error initialising Kubernetes support.
io.fabric8.kubernetes.client.KubernetesClientException: Operation: [get]  for kind: [Pod]  with name: [zalenium-zalenium-hub-75d85c5cb-fkxtl]  in namespace: [default]  failed.`

Comment: Just thought of the fact that RBAC is not enabled on AKS (Azure), and the cluster-admon clusterrole does not exist.

Comment: locally with minikube I get it to work when I create a clusterrolebinding of the zalenium-zalenium serviceaccount with the clusterrole cluster-admin.

Comment: Just a thought. The initial error message is java. I believe that's a zalenium error. The new one says you no pod with that name has been found. Did you get it doing `kubectl get pod ...`?

Comment: hi @suren, when I do the helm install then a describe pod gives an error that a get on the pod failed. the name of the pod in the log matches the pod that is started. when binding the cluser-admin role with the SA account it works. Unfortunately on AKS there is no cluster-admin account.

Comment: I deployed the application the exact same way on an ACS cluster (Azure) and it works.